# Optimal paint for UV fluorescence?

Tags: visible-light, light-emitting-diodes, fluorescence

If we assume that a light source with 365 nm is the optimal source for how strongly we perceive UV light when it hits a UV fluorescent surface, what would be the optimal colour to paint such a surface for maximum UV fluorescence?

Example: I am planning on using a UV led for a visual effect and have been told to use 365 nm LED's for the strongest visual effect. However, I have been unable to find suggestions on what paint (in regards to colour) to paint the fluorescent surface in that will be hit by the UV light. Does it matter? Would a blue fluorescent surface appear to shine stronger than a green fluorescent surface if all else is equal?

Comment: Re, "What would be the optimal color...?" Wrong question. Different pigments or dyes can appear as the same color when illuminated by one light source, and yet appear as different colors when illuminated by a different light source.  You could have two pigments/dyes that both look a certain color under typical room lighting, and yet one could strongly fluoresce under 365nm light, and the other, not at all.

Comment: Re, "assume that a light source with 365 nm is the optimal..." I would not assume that the optimal wavelength for exciting one pigment was the same as the optimal wavelength for exciting a different pigment.... Unless I was optimizing for _cost._ When cost dominates the equation, then UV LEDs are the best choice in a lot of applications.

Comment: P.S.: You might want to have a look at [DayGlo brand](https://www.amazon.com/DayGlo-Fluorescent-Solvent-Based-Brushing-Enamel/dp/B01MEHS70Y/) pigments.